# An application keeps being called each time I log in to user

Tags: boot, startup, startx, armbian, rc.local

I've been using Armbian Buster v5.10 and configuring it for a project.

I remember making some changes so that startx runs automatically at startup.

Each time I log in via `su myUser` then `startx` gets called.

I don't need this anymore. So I edited `/etc/rc.local` so that it only contains the bash headers and `exit 0` and rebooted.

But startx still gets called each time I log in. I think I must have changed another setting somewhere but I cannot find it. I've searched online for other ways to do this but I can only find mentions of rc.local.

Please can someone help?

Comment: Have you check `/etc/profile.d` or the user's `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @NasirRiley That is the answer thank you. I had to change the users ~/.bashrc :)

Comment: As you have confirmed, I have posted it as an answer. You can accept it so that others can reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have verified this in your response to my comment, I'm going to post it as an answer so that it can help others:

As this is happening at login, check the user's `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/profile.d` for `startx`. Those shell init scripts are the two most common places where things are set at login as both files are sourced at login.